# MutationObserver not detecting Height changes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a container with header and main block inside, like this

```
<div #container class="container">
  <div #header class="header">...</div>

  <div class="main">
    <lp-chart [chartHeight]="chartHeight"></lp-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my goal is to detect `#header` height changes and set height to `#main` component.
So you can imagine,

```
the whole #container is - 100%, 
#header, for example, 50px,  
and el inside #main block should be `100% - 50px`
```

And everything works almost fine, except, on the left part of the page I have sidebar which can be opened or collapsed, so window is not resized, but header will change it's height depends on that,
[image]
but my `MutationObserver` doesn't detect it.

This `detailsHeader` change it's height in css as `max-height: 150px;`,(so while sidebar collapsed header height 50px, if opened - expands to 150) and I think thats the reason, but maybe I miss something.
Here's some part of my code:
service

```
setupHeightMutationObserver(el: ElementRef): Observable<HeightAndWidth> {
    const observerable$ = new Observable<HeightAndWidth>(observer => {
      const callback = () => observer.next(this.getHeightAndWidthObject(el));
      const elementObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);
      const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
      elementObserver.observe(el.nativeElement, config);
    });

    return observerable$
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(50),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      );
  }

private getHeightAndWidthObject(el: ElementRef): HeightAndWidth {
    const newValues = new HeightAndWidth();
    newValues.height = el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    newValues.width = el.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    return newValues;
  }
```

component

```
@ViewChild('details') private details: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('detailsHeader') private detailsHeader: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.subscription$ = this.elementResizeService.setupHeightMutationObserver(this.detailsHeader)
      .subscribe((newValues: HeightAndWidth) => this.calculateChartSize(newValues));
  }

calculateChartSize(newValues: HeightAndWidth): void {
    const detailsHeader = this.elementResizeService.doDivHeightChange(newValues);
    const detailsHeight = this.details.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const height = detailsHeight - detailsHeader.height - 10;
    this.chartHeight = height;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Use the resize Observer api instead for geometry changes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API

Comment: Also, not sure if this is a typo - `<div #conteiner class="container">`

Comment: @NVRM Resize Observer doesn't work in IE, but  my project unfortunately should support it

Comment: @wahwahwah yeah, it's a typo.. thanks!

Comment: It's really hard to tell because you haven't included your sidebar in the html. Think about the relationships between the elements on your page and what you want to adjust with the frame size change... is your sidebar a *child* element; inheriting css you dont want it to?

Comment: This sidebar has it's own long component chain but in two words its structure looks like `#wholeBlock` inside which are `#sidebar` and `#container` (but each of them devided to small component, so it's hard to pass some value from one to another), it's positioned by flex, so it's not a child element

Comment: Don't forget to specify your criterias next time. This one -support in IE- is a major pain in the ass. IDK why you still have tow work with this trash. TELL your boss that this is is an immense lost of time and energy. Crap must goes away. Whatever he is saying, your boss is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you specified that you can't use the [resize Observer api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API).

Another possibility is to attach a `resize` event on the `window` object. And then read your particular element dimensions at this moment.

**This is untested in IE. But It looks supported since IE4.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

[image]

And does not work well as a snippet here (Try to either resize, zoom, go full page, or resize your console to trigger the `alert()`).

Notice the use of `%` and `vh` css units, does not matter, this is to show that the result is in pixels anyway.

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", getSizes, false)
        
function getSizes(){
  let header = document.getElementById("header")
  alert(header.clientWidth +"px x "+ header.clientHeight + "px")
}
```

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height:12vh;
  border: 3px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>
```